# Invoke autosys job from .net

Tags: c#, autosys

I am having a job scheduled with autosys on Unix server. I want to run that job from a .net windows application on button click from another machine. Can anybody give me some hint how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

A. Install the Autosys client on the Windows machine, connect it to your Autosys instance, and use it to issue a FORCE_STARTJOB command whenever needed.

B. Install PuTTY on the Windows machine and have it log in to the UNIX server via Plink to send the FORCE_STARTJOB command whenever needed.